# Data Repository using MemoryCache

Tags: multithreading, repository, signals, memorycache, event-wait-handle

I built a homebrew data entity repository with a factory that defines retention policy by type (e.g. absolute or sliding expiration).  The policy also specifies the cache type as httpcontext request, session, or application.  A MemoryCache is maintained by a caching proxy in all 3 cache types.  Anyhow, I have a data entity service tied to the repository which does the load and save for our primary data entity.  The idea is you use the entity repository and don't need to care if the entity is cached or retrieved from it's data source (db in this case).

An obvious assumption would be that you would need to synchronise the load/save events as you would need to save the cached entity before loading the entity from it's data source.

So I was investigating a data integrity issue in production today... :)

Today I read there can be a good long gap between the entity being removed from the MemoryCache and the CacheItemRemovedCallback event firing (default 20 seconds).  The simple lock I had around the load and save data ops was insufficient.  Furthermore the CacheItemRemovedCallback was in it's own context outside of HttpContext making things interesting.  It meant I needed to make the callback function static as I was potentially assigning a disposed instance to the event.

So once I realised there was was the possibility of a gap whereby my data entity no longer existed in cache but might not have been saved to it's data source might explain the 3 corrupt orders out of 5000.  While filling out a long form it would be easy to perform work beyond the policy's 20 minute sliding expiration on the primary data entity.  That means if they happen to submit at the same moment of expiration an interesting race condition between the load (via request context) and save (via cache expired callback) emerges.

With a simple lock it was the roll of the dice, would save or load win?  Clearly we need a save before the next load from the data source (db).  Ideally when an item expires from the cache it is atomically written to it's data source.  with the entity gone from the cache but the expired callback not yet fired a load operation can slip in.  In this case the entity will not be found in the cache so will default to load from the data source.  However, as the save operation may not have commenced resulting in data integrity corruption and will likely clobber your now saved cached data.

To accomplish synchronisation I need a named signalling lock so I settled on EventWaitHandle.  A named lock is created per user which is < 5000.  This allows the Load to wait on a signal from the expired event which Saves the entity (whose thread exists in its own context outside HttpContext).  So in the save it is easy to grab the existing name handle and signal the Load to continue once the Save is complete.

I also have a redundancy where it times out and logs each 10 seconds block by the save operation.  As I said, the default is meant to be 20 seconds between an entity being removed form MemoryCache and it being conscious of it to fire the event which in turn saves the entity.

Thank you to anyone who followed my ramblings through all that.  Given the nature of the sync requirements was the EventWaitHandle lock the best solution?

Comment: Maybe using MemoryCache is this way is not a very good design.

Comment: It's always tempting to call something a bad design past a certain level of complexity.  However, I would argue that it's not unreasonable to handle caching across threads nor is it unreasonable to need to synchronise said threads.  In regards to the MemoryCache, I doubt it would be worth trying to invent one better.  I would love to hear an argument to the contrary, or alternatives, or about a better synchronisation mechanism.

Comment: Maybe [redis](https://redis.io/topics/introduction) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I wanted to post what I did to address the issue.  I made multiple changes to the design to create a tidier solution which did not require a named sync object and allowed me to use a simple lock instead.

First the data entity repository is a singleton which was stored in the request cache.  This front end of the repository is detached from the cache's themselves.  I changed it to reside in the session cache instead which becomes important below.

Second I changed the event for the expired entity to route through the data entity repository above.

Third I changed the MemoryCache event from RemovedCallback to UpdateCallback**.

Last, we tie it all together with a regular lock in the data entity repository which is is the user's session and the gap-less expiry event routing through the same allowing the lock to cover load and save (expire) operations.

---

** These events are funny in that A) you can't subscribe to both and B) UpdateCallback is called before the item is removed from the cache but it is not called when you explicitly remove the item (aka myCache.Remove(entity) won't call event but UpdateCallback will).  We made the decision if the item was being forcefully removed from the cache that we didn't care.  This happens when the user changes company or clears their shopping list.  So these scenarios won't fire the event so the entity may never be saved to the DB's cache tables.  While it might have been nice for debugging purposes it wasn't worth dealing with the limbo state of an entity's existence to use the RemovedCallback which had 100% coverage.